# inkscape save image svg does not store curve

Tags: image, svg, latex, inkscape

I have a svg file with [xml code](http://pastebin.com/7mqSmuNJ)

[image]

The code

```
convert curve.svg curve.png
```

works fine.

But using inkscape:

```
inkscape -e curve.png curve.svg
```

> Background RRGGBBAA: ffffff00
>
> Area 0:0:1000:600 exported to 1000 x 600 pixels (90 dpi)
>
> Bitmap saved as: curve.png

Gives me an image with no curve:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inkscape does not appear to like commas in the `d` attribute value of `<path>`. I don't know if this is a bug, a known limitation, or because of the SVG spec; don't really know much about SVGs--sorry. :-)

However, if you remove the commas from the value of `d`, it seems to work fine.

One possible way to do this on Linux is with a simple Awk command (not very robust, but works for your particular file--just what I tried in troubleshooting):

```
awk '/<path /{gsub(", L", " L")}{print}' with-commas.svg > working.svg
```

If you find you need to massage the XML in a "production-grade" application, please use an actual XML parser and remove the commas appropriately, rather than relying on my silly Awk script. :-)

Comment: Commas are only allowed between numbers in a d attribute. In this case they are not so the path is invalid and inkscape is quite right to reject it.